# Key bindings specific to a buffer

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, file-local-variables

Is it possible to set key bindings specific to buffer?

I have the following in one of my org files:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (local-set-key (kbd "<f10>") 'some-custom-defun-specific-to-this-buffer)
# End:
```

But this binding persists for other org-mode files too. If I open a file with a different major mode, then my default key binding kicks in.

It looks like `local-set-key` is setting bindings specific to the major-mode not specific to the buffer.

**How can I have bindings that activate only in a particular buffer?**

Comment: Oh wow, you're right: "The binding goes in the current buffer's local map,
which in most cases is shared with all other buffers in the same major mode." I never knew that.

Comment: Now that I think about it, `local-unset-key` hooked with `org-mode-hook` might work if that is executed before the `Local Variables:` section is.

Comment: Or you could make a minor mode with a semi sparse keymap and toggle it using `Local Variables:`

Comment: @Vamsi Thanks! This is an elegant solution! I have updated your solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486934/file-specific-key-binding-in-emacs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For closure, here is an answer that expands upon my comment. I define a minor mode with the required keybinding and toggle it in the required buffer using file local variables.

```
  (define-minor-mode my-org-buffer-local-mode
    "Minor mode to simulate buffer local keybindings."
    :init-value nil)
  (define-key my-org-buffer-local-mode-map (kbd "<f10>") 'some-custom-defun-specific-to-this-buffer)
```

You can toggle it in necessary files by setting the local variables section at the end of the file as follows. You can also change or add the keybinding here. **You will still need to define different minor modes for each buffer that maps the same key-sequence to different commands.**

```
 # Local Variables:
 # my-org-buffer-local-mode: t
 # eval:(define-key my-org-buffer-local-mode-map (kbd "<f10>") 'some-other-custom-defun-specific-to-this-buffer)
 # End:
```

Comment: @kaushalmodi: You might want to spin off your edits into a separate answer since it is more complete. Also, you would not be able to map the same key-sequence to two different functions simultaneously unless you use a buffer specific name.

Comment: I get this error: `eval-buffer: Symbol's value as variable is void: my-org-buffer-local-mode-map` when I try to run this `(define-minor-mode my-org-buffer-local-mode
    "Minor mode to simulate buffer local keybindings."
    :init-value nil)
  (define-key my-org-buffer-local-mode-map (kbd "<f10>") 'some-custom-defun-specific-to-this-buffer) `

Comment: I also get the same error. any idea?

Comment: @incandescentman call (make-keymap) with `:keymap` keyword, check https://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/02/06/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a generic way to set buffer-specific key bindings.

- Create a temporary minor mode (save the below snippet to `temp-mode.el` and `require` it in your `init.el`.
- Enable that `temp-mode` minor mode and define that minor-mode's keymap only in the buffer(s) you need.

*Put the below `Local Variables` snippet in the buffer where you want the custom key binding. Below are examples of `org-mode` files.*

*In buffer ONE*

```org
# Local Variables:
# eval: (temp-mode 1)
# eval: (define-key temp-mode-map (kbd "<f10>") 'function-ONE)
# End:
```

If some other buffer redefines the same key-binding using,

*In buffer TWO*

```org
# Local Variables:
# eval: (temp-mode 1)
# eval: (define-key temp-mode-map (kbd "<f10>") 'function-TWO)
# End:
```

then the new binding become effective on doing `M-x revert-buffer`.

This is what I would do if I need to switch between these two buffers very frequently and if I have to use the <kbd>F10</kbd> binding in both:

- Work in buffer ONE, `C-x C-s` (save) and switch to buffer TWO
- `revert-buffer` (refresh bindings), work in buffer TWO, `C-x C-s` and switch to buffer ONE
- `revert-buffer` (refresh bindings), work in buffer ONE, `C-x C-s` and switch to buffer TWO

*But I would rather bind the different buffer-specific commands to different keys.*

---

### Temporary minor mode

```el
;; temp-mode.el
;; Temporary minor mode
;; Main use is to enable it only in specific buffers to achieve the goal of
;; buffer-specific keymaps

(defvar temp-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)
  "Keymap while temp-mode is active.")

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode temp-mode
  "A temporary minor mode to be activated only specific to a buffer."
  nil
  :lighter " Temp"
  temp-mode-map)

(provide 'temp-mode)
```